# Apache Commons Configuration Cant save

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I am using Apache Commons Configuration to keep some properties in a properties file located in a package `re/iprocu/coperativeerp/config/payment/configurations.properties`

```
private PropertiesConfiguration configs = new  PropertiesConfiguration("re/iprocu/coperativeerp/config/payment/configurations.properties");
configs.setAutoSave(true);
configs.setProperty(date.getYear()+"-"+date.getMonthValue()+"-01", offsetMember);
```

The problem is when i run the above code i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: Failed to auto-save
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.possiblySave(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:753)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.clearProperty(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:799)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.setProperty(AbstractConfiguration.java:485)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.setProperty(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:788)
```

**Update**

Apache Commons Configuration V. 1.10

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
     <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you tell the version of the Commons-configuration jar are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save a configuration that points to a file within a JAR. Try using a configuration file that is located outside of your JAR and you'll see that auto-save option works correctly.

**EDIT**

You can put the file both in a JAR and in the same relative path in one of the default locations. Here's what [the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_properties.html#Properties_files) says.

> If you do not specify an absolute path, the file will be searched automatically in the following locations:
>
> - in the current directory
> - in the user home directory
> - in the classpath

So, if for instance you have a default properties file in you JAR, located at `conf/configuration.properties`, you can put the properties either in user's home directory under the same relative path - e.g. on Linux `/home/username/conf/configuration.properties` or in the same directory with your JAR file. Both should be secure enough.

Comment: Then the big question is where to keep the properties file(the location should be relative path and sure that there will be no security issues with it) ?

Answer (score 1):

That issue can be connected with inproper version of commons configuration. I had exactly same dependency in my pom and problems arose from it. What I've done is included such dependencies instead

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Commons-configuration2 uses commons-beanutils which is optional, that is why I've
also included second dependency.